# SQL Manager for MySQL - foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I would like to make **personId** Foreign Key using this software and later connect with table **country**. Do you know where is this option?

[image]
[here they show option for foreign Key - but I have another view](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs5435.html)

Comment: Why not read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed before I didn`t find this example.

[here they show](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs5462.html)